# Integration Problem with a particle moving along x-axis

Tags: integration

How would you solve this problem?

If we have a particle moving along the x-axis with acceleration $a(t) = 9*t^2 - 4*t - 8$, (time must be positive or 0). The particle is at rest when t = 0, located 7 units to the right of the origin.

How would you find the total distance traveled in the first four seconds, and

the particle's exact position after 4 seconds?

I understand the concept of using the 2nd integral, but I tried it several times and obtained different answers. Please provide the process along with the answers for the 2 questions.

Thanks!

Comment: integral of accelration is velocity and integral of velocity is distance time  function

Comment: Yes. My main problem is that I keep on getting different answers.

Comment: so you need double integral,what did you get  when double integrate?

Comment: dont we have additional information?

Comment: or maybe i did not understand something

Comment: This was everything provided. I will check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let us integrate  first time,we get

$v(t)=3*t^3-2*t^2-8*t+c$

if we integrate any more we get

$s(t)=3*t^4/4-2*t^3/3-4*t^2+c*t+c_1$

now if $s(0)=7$

then clearly $c_1=7$

dont we have additional information?to determine $c$?

Answer (score 0):

$v(t) = \displaystyle \int a(t) dt$ means that $v(t)=3t^3-2t^2-8t+c_1$

At $t=0$, the object is at rest, that is $v(0)=0$, thus $c_1=0$

Then, $s(t) = \displaystyle \int v(t) dt$  means that
$s(t)=3t^4/4-2t^3/3-4t^2+c_2$

At $t=0$, $s(0)=7$, thus $c_2=7$  $\implies s(t)=3t^4/4-2t^3/3-4t^2+7$

The position at $t=4$ is simply $s(4)$ while the distance travelled is $\displaystyle \int_0^4 |v(t)|dt$